# Mapping Object Data from ReduxPromise

Tags: reactjs, redux-promise-middleware

Trying to map an object that was returned from a promise, i am using react-router 4 and redux, redux-promise. the data has been returned as a promise but i cant seem to map it. If i remember correctly, the render() returns the renderBanner function and renders it there but i am a little unsure of how to map this data as i want to just grab the img and map it.

edit: example (uses different api but same process)

component file

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Grid, Image } from 'react-bootstrap';
// import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { fetchAdverts } from '../actions/adverts_action';

class FullWidthBannerAd extends Component {
  componentDidMount(props) {
    this.props.fetchAdverts();
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    // this.state = {
    //   data: []
    // };
    console.log('Props Contains:', props);
  };

  renderBanner(props) {
    console.log('renderBanner Contains:', props);
    return (
      <div>
        hello
      </div>
    )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Grid>
        {this.renderBanner()}
      </Grid>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    adverts: state.adverts
  };
}

export default connect(fetchAdverts)(FullWidthBannerAd);
```

promise returned

```
[,…]
0
:{_id: "57bf06e2ad5f52130098ae1c", sort_order: null, img: "e670cf43-9ed7-45f4-987d-d899af472f4c.jpg",…}
_id:"57bf06e2ad5f52130098ae1c"
img:"e670cf43-9ed7-45f4-987d-d899af472f4c.jpg"
```

Comment: so your promise returned data is an array which includes objects and each object has an image which you want to get?

Comment: yes thats correct

Comment: in your render() you can check if theres is this.props.data, call return renderBanner, if not return null, and in renderBanner function everything is correct, you can return <img src={adverts.img} />

Comment: updated post. when i console log the constructor an object is send back with a payload of data however when using the renderBanner and logging props i get back undefined, if its coming back undefined does that mean the mapping will not work

Comment: ive added a repo that uses a different api for its data but same principle and same issue. constructor can see props but has no state data and renderBanner cannot see either: https://github.com/KadenLag/ows

Comment: first of all, componentDidMount doesn't have an argument props, and also in your renderBanner function you don't have any props. in react if you want to get props outside of constructor you call this.props, because your component is a class. So, the answer of your question is write this.props not props in your function, and remove props argument from componentDidMount()

Answer (score 0):

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Grid, Image } from 'react-bootstrap';
// import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { fetchAdverts } from '../actions/adverts_action';

class FullWidthBannerAd extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    // this.state = {
    //   data: []
    // };
    console.log('Props Contains:', props);
  };
  
   componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.props);
    this.props.fetchAdverts();
  }

  renderBanner() {
    console.log('renderBanner Contains:', this.props);
    return (
      <div>
        hello
      </div>
    )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Grid>
        {this.renderBanner()}
      </Grid>
    );
  }
}
```

change your code to this. hope this will help you

Comment: that brings it in, but im having a problem with mapping it, when i console.log this.props.payload i get [[PromiseValue]] then my data which has 3 objects 0, 1, 2 inside with a image property which i am trying to get. how do i map through the [[PromiseValue]] if i try console.log the data with this.props.payload.data it comes back undefined